# Audio file not working on device but it is working on simulator

Tags: iphone, ipad, audio, video, ios-simulator

I am playing audio in iphone app but problem is that it works fine on simulator but it is not working on device here is my code it just closes the app when this code runs.

```
         NSString*thePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"MP3"];
    NSURL*url=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:thePath];



    //NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://celeritas-solutions.com/pah_brd_v1/productivo/1.mp3"];
    mp = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    [[mp moviePlayer] prepareToPlay];
    [[mp moviePlayer] setUseApplicationAudioSession:NO];
    [[mp moviePlayer] setShouldAutoplay:YES];
    [[mp moviePlayer] setControlStyle:2];
    [[mp moviePlayer] setRepeatMode:MPMovieRepeatModeOne];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mp];
```

Here is the video code this also works on simulator but not on iphone

```
         NSString*thePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"MP4"];
    NSURL*url=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:thePath];
    //NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://celeritas-solutions.com/pah_brd_v1/productivo/1.mp4"];
    mp = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    [[mp moviePlayer] prepareToPlay];
    [[mp moviePlayer] setUseApplicationAudioSession:NO];
    [[mp moviePlayer] setShouldAutoplay:YES];
    [[mp moviePlayer] setControlStyle:2];
    [[mp moviePlayer] setRepeatMode:MPMovieRepeatModeOne];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mp];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code...

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"mp3"];
AVAudioPlayer* theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
theAudio.delegate=self;
[theAudio play];
```

first check the file is stored in your project folder or not and also that variable is not `nil`.

Also Check Out this Link [play-mp3-files-with-iphone-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973902/play-mp3-files-with-iphone-sdk)

And this tutorial [how-to-play-audio-and-video-in-iphone](http://iphoneapp-dev.blogspot.in/2011/07/how-to-play-audio-and-video-in-iphone.html)

**UPDATE:**

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *Mpplayer =[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL: [url standardizedURL]];
Mpplayer.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeUnknown;  
[self presentModalViewController:Mpplayer animated:YES];
[[Mpplayer moviePlayer] play];
```

Comment: @JdeveloperIphone oh ok dude then see this link.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058067/i-have-a-problem-with-mpmovieplayercontroller-iphone-sdk

Comment: @JdeveloperIphone also check this tutorial.. http://iphoneapp-dev.blogspot.in/2011/07/how-to-play-audio-and-video-in-iphone.html i hope this is helpful to you.. :)

Comment: same code if i am using any server url file then works fine on device this same problem also with video

Comment: don't know what is the reason for not playing on device it works fine on simulator i have tried all

Comment: hey check the internet connection of device and some setting about that.. check that... bcoz its working perfact in my project now..

Answer (score 3):

First add AVFoundation.framework and add below code.

in .h file

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

and .m file

```
 [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
```